# Network Manager Error

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

I'm having a problem here, some times when i'm using the Internet, my browser lost connection with some sites for few seconds no matter which browser i'm using in the moment. I don't know if this error "nm_device_get_device_type: assertion 'NM_IS_DEVICE (self)' failed" that I found in syslog.1 is related with that problem.

I've changed the network card already.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Is it a wired or wireless connection?

Comment: It is using wired connection.

Comment: First, `/var/log/syslog.1` doesn't contain the most current data. Second, watch the logs! In a terminal window, type `journalctl --follow`. Then work as usual. When the problem happens, `^C` the `journalctl --follow` and look at the log messages for the event.

Comment: I've ran that command it returned this https://pastebin.mozilla.org/?dl=9031598 so far.